# Known Facebook places not showing with Graph API search

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the following Facebook API call to grab a list of places within a certain distance from a point on a map like so:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/search?type=place&center=XX.XXXXXXXXXXXXX,-XX.XXXXXXXXXX&distance=8100`

With the user access token I'm using, the request returns 226 results, all of them are associated with a Facebook page.

I'm not sure, however, if the results are complete. For example, there is a restaurant just over 5000 meters from the coordinates in my query that's not showing up in the results. The restaurant has a Facebook page and has an address associated with it. There are other pages that also do not show.

So how does a Facebook page become associated with a "place" on Facebook?

Comment: And the user whose token you are using is able to see that restaurant page on Facebook? The page doesn’t have any access restrictions set, that that user might not qualify for?

Comment: Right.

So, I've been able to solve the problem (well, at least work around it), by making many different queries using different coordinates for the `center` key.

I suspect Facebook is just making things hit and miss on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of token do you use? (user, app, client, page)
Also, the place might not be registred right or might not be public information. 
Not sure though...

Comment: As mentioned, I'm using a "user token."